# Initializing array of structures with function pointer member in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

I am having trouble in initializing an array of structures with a function pointer as a member in it.

```
class Record
{
    private:
    typedef void (*display_fn_t) ();
    struct record {
        int a;
        display_fn_t disp;
    };
    static const record rec[];

    void disp1() { cout << "Display 1 with a string to display" << endl; }
    void disp2() { cout << "Display 2 with an integer to display" << endl; }

    public:
    int find() { /* logic to find the record comes here */ }
    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            rec[i].disp();
        }
    }
}

const Record::record Record::rec[] = {
    { 10, disp1 },
    { 11, disp2 }
};

int main()
{
    Record r;
    if (r.find())
        r.display();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code, I am getting the following compilation error:

> mca_record.cpp:56: error: argument of type ‘void (Record::)()’ does
>   not match ‘void (*)()’

Comment: Pointers to member functions are *not* the same as pointers to non-member functions. There must be hundreds or even thousands of duplicates here on SO. The problem is that a pointer to a member function needs an actual object instance to be called on, while pointers to non-member functions doesn't.

Comment: Also, you might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Also, missing semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong and isn't using the appropriate operators.

Fixing a multitude of syntax errors, and stripping out the unrelated `find` operation, then utilizing proper member function pointers and `operator ->*` gives the following (one of several ways to do this):

```
#include <iostream>

class Record
{
private:
    typedef void (Record::*display_memfn_t)();
    struct record
    {
        int a;
        display_memfn_t disp;
    };

    static const record rec[];

    void disp1() { std::cout << "Display 1 with a string to display" << std::endl; }
    void disp2() { std::cout << "Display 2 with an integer to display" << std::endl; }

public:
    void display();
};

const Record::record Record::rec[] =
{
    { 10, &Record::disp1 },
    { 11, &Record::disp2 }
};

void Record::display()
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof rec/sizeof*rec; ++i)
        (this->*(rec[i].disp))();
}

int main()
{
    Record r;
    r.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Display 1 with a string to display
Display 2 with an integer to display
```

Compare it to your existing code, and not in particular that pointers to member functions are not simply pointers to functions. They require different handling and generally different operators to utilize. [**See here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) for different methods of member access (both variable and function).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig. I need the find function as there goes some logic to fetch some values which are used in display functions. However, I can make use of few tweaks you mentioned. That's really cool.

Answer (score 1):

To make the call work you must invoke it like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            (*rec[i].disp)();
        }
```

And initialize the table this way:

```
const Record::record Record::rec[] = {
    { 10, &Record::disp1 },
    { 11, &Record::disp2 }
};
```

Comment: On looking closely, @WhozCraig has solved my problem already. But +1 for your short description attacking the problem statement directly. Thanks